# How to override "style.scss" from component based scss in angular-7?

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have just started a angular-7 based web application with sass, when I import scss within "styles.scss" then it works perfectly throughout the application but when I am trying to add/override css within component(profile.component.scss) then it's not working.

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Angular: 7.1.4
Node: 11.6.0
```

Here are "angular.json" css structure of the application ---

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
  "node_modules/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css",
  "src/styles.scss"
],
```

Here are "styles.scss" structure that added for the application ---

```
@import "assets/scss/custom-mixin";
@import "assets/scss/header";
@import "assets/scss/page";
@import "assets/scss/footer";

@import "assets/scss/login";
@import "assets/scss/profile";
@import "assets/scss/profile-edit";
@import "assets/scss/privacy";
@import "assets/scss/search";
@import "assets/scss/testimonial";
@import "assets/scss/public-profile";
@import "assets/scss/card-builder";

@import "assets/scss/rtl";
@import "assets/scss/responsive";
```

Please check the above described structure and let me know if you find any error/mistakes within this and provide me specific way to work both css for the application.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add new CSS file and include below the `styles.scss` then you can override the CSS.

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
  "node_modules/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css",
  "src/styles.scss",
  "src/custom.css"
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but the thing is not that to add new css file to override this. Suppose you have a component named "profile" and you have the .scss(profile.component.scss) file for this component, but when I am writing css properties on this file this is not effected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the angular compiler where to look for your scss files.

Add this to your angular.json file above your "styles" property:

```
                "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                    "includePaths": [
                        "src/theming"
                    ]
                }
```

Now create a directory src/themeing and add whatever .scss files you want.

You can then `@import 'mycustomstuff'` where src/theming/mycustomstuff.scss exists.

Hope this helps! If you're still stuck please provide us with your component.ts file(s).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but the thing is not that to add new css file to override this. Suppose you have a component named "profile" and you have the .scss(profile.component.scss) file for this component, but when I am writing css properties on this file this is not effected.